# Photo sizing, photo popping

Tags: themes, size, edit, tumblr, photo

So I'm using the "ashen" theme for my tumblr page, and I'm trying to change the size of two-columned photos. I'm changing the size of the photos, (width, height) to no avail with this theme, but I really like how it's all set up. If I  could just change the size and have it work, that would be great. But I feel like the theme has some code preventing me from doing that, or it's coming into conflict with something else.

I'm also attempting to have normal photos pop like photosets, with the larger image appearing upon clicking. The same way photosets do.

I am aware this theme does not use the classic "lightbox" figuration of tumblr, so it *should* be relatively simple to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show use an example of what you have tried? A live link showcasing the issue would also help.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to advertise my blog or anything, not sure if it's against the rules. But my blog is omyn.tumblr.com and the theme I use seems to not allow me to change the size of my posts at all. The width it will allow, but it only makes it more than one column when I go high enough.